# Kubernetes deployment not doing rolling update

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have the following deployment in kubernetes:

```
 apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
 kind: Deployment
 metadata:
   labels:
     run: hello-node
   name: hello-node
   namespace: default
 spec:
   replicas: 2
   selector:
     matchLabels:
       run: hello-node
   strategy:
     rollingUpdate:
       maxSurge: 2
       maxUnavailable: 0
     type: RollingUpdate
   template:
     metadata:
       creationTimestamp: null
       labels:
         run: hello-node
     spec:
       containers:
       - image: <image>:<tag>
         imagePullPolicy: Always
         name: hello-node
         livenessProbe:
           httpGet:
             path: /rest/hello
             port: 8081
           initialDelaySeconds: 15
           timeoutSeconds: 1
         ports:
         - containerPort: 8081
           protocol: TCP
         resources:
           requests:
             cpu: 400m
         terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
       dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
       restartPolicy: Always
       securityContext: {}
       terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

The issue is that when I update my deployment to let's say a new version of my image, `Kubernetes` will instantly kill both pods with the old image, and bring two new pods with the new image. While the new pods are booting up I experience an interruption of service.

Because of the `rollingUpdate` and the `livenessProbe` I'm expecting `Kubernetes` to do the following:

1. Start one pod with the new image
2. Wait for the new pod to be healthy based on the `livenessProbe`
3. Kill one pod with the old image
4. Repeat until all pods have been migrated

I am missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is `readinessProbe`.

The default state of `Liveness` before the initial delay is `Success`, whereas the default state of `Readiness` before the initial delay is `Failure`.

If you’d like your container to be killed and restarted if a probe fails, then specify a `LivenessProbe` and a `RestartPolicy` of `Always` or `OnFailure`.

If you’d like to start sending traffic to a pod only when a probe succeeds, specify a `ReadinessProbe`.

See [container probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) for more details.

To have the rolling update behavior you described, set `maxSurge` to `1` (default value). This tells the Deployment to "scale up at most one more replica at a time". See [docs of `maxSurge`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#max-surge) for more details.

Comment: thanks for that. THe `readinessProbe` definitively helped with the interruption of service. Now `k8s` will start 2 new pods, wait for them to be ready, and when they are it will kill the 2 old pods. This is better but I'm still not getting the rolling update behaviour. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "not getting the rolling update behavior"? Note that the `.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxSurge` is set to `2` and `maxUnavailable` set to `0`, this means that you expect the Deployment to have at most 4 replicas and at least 2 available replicas (since you didn't set `minReadySeconds` that implies 2 running replicas). So what you see is expected.

Comment: From the video on the Kubernetes website, I understood that during a rolling update, kubernetes would alternate between removing old pods and adding new ones. If there were 3 pods it would be [3,0], [2.1], [1,2], [0,3]. So there is a period where the traffic is served by both versions of the service. I understand that in the old way of doing rolling update (I.e. not with deployment object) there is a parameter to define the period between each update. Did I miss understand?

Comment: I guess you meant `--update-period` flag of `kubectl rolling-update`. If you want the new pod to wait for a while after it's ready before you consider it to be available, set `minReadySeconds`. If you want it to scale up/down new/old replicas one by one you can set `maxSurge` to 1 (the default value). It's acting as expected since you tell the Deployment to scale up 2 more at a time. See [deployment's doc on maxSurge](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#max-surge)

Comment: ok many thanks, I had misunderstood what `maxSurge` was. Can you add details about `maxSurge` in the answer? Then I can accept the answer.